# what to choose between Vaadin and Spring for JEE

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to implement a java web application. The main functionality is getting data from web services and show it with chars. 
After some research i am facing a problem in choosing between `Vaadin` and `Spring`. i see the vaadin demo, it has a very huge number of good UI components and what i liked in vaadin is that the front-end is developped with java, so there is no need to have a good knowledge in front-end frameworks like JS and html5.

this application is a dashboard for data coming from many android users. it shows data of users. the application has 3 roles(actors). what i want to know is: is there any limitation in spring or vaadin and which framework is better to use

Please help me to choose the adequate framework
Thanks

Comment: there is no clear answer to that.  how should we know what use-cases you have, what demands your customer has etc.  there is no way around to find that out for yourself.

Comment: Spring and Vaadin... Rarely have I seen so _please compare these apples to these oranges_ question on SO... As mentioned before, you need to at least list your use cases, constraints etc.

Comment: this application is a dashboard for data coming from many android users. it shows data of users. the application has 3 roles(actors).
what i want to know is: is there any limitation in spring or vaadin and which framework is better to use

Comment: Ok i edited my question :)

Comment: Since you have to build a View application forget about Spring, have a look to [Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts).

Answer (score 3):

Vaadin has not hard limitations, it's software after all. 
But it could be more difficult to scale: a vaadin application is a stateful one, the session is used quite extensively.

Spring is a bit vague I suppose that you mean Spring MVC + some templating system or maybe a rest spring mvc client with a js gui.

Anyway, for a dashboard that will not be used by thousands of users I'd use Vaadin! Even more if you are not very comfortable with javascript, html and css.

Vaadin also has the push feature that could prove useful for a dashboard.

Moreover Vaadin doesn't exclude Spring you can use both.

Hope this is useful

Comment: thank you for this answer. another thing can i change the vaadin components styles with css or whatever. and does vaadin support animation in UI ??

Comment: Yes you can [skin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html) Vaadin, you can even build your own components and afaik Vaadin supports some kind of animations (like drag and drop) and have lot of [community built plugins](https://vaadin.com/directory#!browse)